# Is there a way to monitor the progress of a video that is played with a web view in android studio

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to play a list of videos using a web video and i need to mark each one as completed when it has finished playing so that the next one can load immediately but i can't seem to find my way around it. this is my code snippet:

```
 private void playVideo(String lessonURL) {
    WebViewPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().getAllowContentAccess();
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
    WebViewPlayer.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    WebViewPlayer.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebViewPlayer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebViewPlayer.loadUrl(lessonURL);
}
```

The video is playing but then i need mark the current video as completed when it is done playing. How can i implement it?

```
     private boolean isCompleted(){
        //how do i implement this?
     }
```